# Tile (Server) Mechanism for visualizing Data on the Web

Tags: openlayers, data-visualization, gephi

I'm looking to build a simple application that allows the visualization of graphs on the web. Specifically my objective is to:

1. Use Gephi to render a graph at various zoom levels
2. I wish to then cut up these images into tiles
3. I wish to the use a web component similar to what Google Maps uses or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) to stitch these layers together and allow the panning, zomming of the graph.

When thinking about this I figured this approach could be applied to any arbitrary data visualization where one wanted to visualize data at multiple zoom levels and the image rendering had to happen server side.

I would like to know if there are standard stack for implementing such an architecture (or even if the architecture I'm thinking of even makes sense).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create a graph visualization on the web with multiple zoom levels (as in Google Maps) you should take a look at the Seadragon Web Export plugin for Gephi: https://gephi.org/plugins/seadragon/

There's a nice example of a graph visualization in the Gephi Blog: https://gephi.org/2010/graph-visualization-on-the-web-with-gephi-and-seadragon/

Comment: beautiful -- now what I want to do is allow folks to click on nodes so they can see information that is behind a node. Do you think seadragon is a good starting point for this.